# IE11 F12 Developer Tools on Windows 7 functionality missing/not working?

Tags: windows-7-x64, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I was using IE10 on Windows 7 but it is such a buggy piece of you-know-what (hanging, crashing, etc.) that I gave up and installed IE11. It has not hung or crashed since installing. But I **hate** the F12 developer tools! Okay, not completely - there are some very cool new features. What I don't like is that they seem to have **dropped** several features that I really liked! Unless I'm just missing something... I've searched and searched on Google and Microsoft but all of the help I've found only describes the new features. Here is what I'm missing: Color picker, Ruler, and most of all, the Clear browser cache for this domain. They allege to have a Clear browser cache function, but it doesn't work! So when I make changes to my website, in particular changing graphics, the only way I can see the change is to delete all my temporary files from IE. Then I lose **all** of my cookies e.g. for automatically logging in to Stack Overflow! IE version 11.0.9600.16428 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color picker is still available, go to the DOM Explorer tab and there is an eye dropper on the tool bar at the top towards the left. That activates the color picker.

Answer (score 1):

For the issue of serving cached files try toggling on "Always refresh from server" on the network tool (3rd option from the left). This should get you the latest changes from your server.